# Why clear does not clear?

Tags: css, css-float

I've been encountering some problems. I dont know why my div.clear does not do the job. As you can see the button next should be surrounded in the red div. Please check my source thanks!

http://www.w3dominik.com/x/vocabito/dashboard.php

```
<div id="buttonsx">
                    <div id="next">next</div>
                    <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add `overflow:auto` to the button. It works - I tested it.

```
#buttonsx {
    padding: 10px;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: red;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

The reason this was occurring was because the content was collapsing on the button, as it didn't have a set height. Setting `overflow:auto` will force the parent to contain the child.

Comment: Should probably use `overflow: auto` instead, though.

Comment: @GiovanniSilveira Sure, I'll update my answer. Although they both fix the problem.

Comment: They both fix the problem. But hidden overflow can give you other undesired issues later. The true replacement for clearing floats should be `overflow: auto`, and not `hidden`

Answer (score 1):

You have this in your `main.css` at line `126`

```
#buttonsx>div {
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left; /* <-- this is the problem */
}
```

This `float: left;` rule is causing the problem, if you remove `float: left;` from this, it'll work as it suppose to do.

**Screenhot:**

[image]